# Get Vector object from JSONObject

Tags: java, json, vector, casting, addition

I am wondering if there is a way to get a Vector from out of a JSONObject. Let's say I have this :

```
public class Foo
    private JSONObject json;
    public Foo(){
        try{ 
            json=new JSONObject();
            Vector<,F> v=new Vector<,F>(); // pretend like the comma isn't there please 
            json.put("blah", v); ...} catch (JSONException e){...}
    } 
    .
    .
    .
    public void addBlahs(,F goo){
         try{
            Object o=json.get("blah");
            // Since json.get("blah") should be a Vector of .F's, I thought I could do something like this...
            Vector<,F> v=(Vector <,F>) o;
            v.add(goo);} catch (JSONException{ ...}
    }
```

Eclipse gives me a warning saying unchecked type cast. Is it possible to get a certain type of object from a JSONObject and then be able to use that object? I want to add "goo"s to that Vector, but not sure how to properly access it and add to it.

I'm a beginner so go easy on me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put a `Vector` in a `JSONObject`. According to the documentation of [`JSONObject#put(String, Object)`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#put%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29):

> **key** - A key string.
>
> **value** - An object which is the value.
>   It should be of one of these types: Boolean, Double, Integer,
>   JSONArray, JSONObject, Long, String, or the JSONObject.NULL object.

However, you can use an [`JSONArray`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html) instead.